# IntelliSense errors after opening a VS 2005 C++ project in VS 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I've inherited a C++ project that compiled fine in VS2005, but when I open it in VS2010 I get lots of IntelliSense erros like this:

> IntelliSense: expression must have integral or enum type

Actually opening one of the cpp files in the project seems to cause the errors to appear.

Here's an example of the type of line that causes the error.

```
if (pInfoset->Fields->Item["Contact"]->Size <= 0)
```

Comment: If they are just Intellisense errors, throw away your Intellisense DB and let it regenerate. (The SDF file and perhaps even an NCB if it's still there)

Comment: Now it's complaining it can't open \myproject\release\msado15.tli - these errors do seem related to ADO.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken (though I barely have experience with that particular bit of functionality) it's a file generated by VS. Perhaps back it up (just to be sure) and remove it for now. See if it regenerates as well. If not, just copy back the file you have.

Comment: That cleared that and I could compile. However, when I opened a particular cpp  module in the project - I got lots of IntelliSense enum errors again. However, I seem to be able to still compile.

Comment: :( Hmm, that's a bummer. Intellisense can be pretty nasty from time to time. Perhaps it didn't look at some of the included files/directories and is missing some information.

Comment: Is it safe to just ignore the errors?

Comment: If your code works just fine, then yes. Intellisense errors in practice do not necessarily mean your code has a problem (unfortunately). But make sure you check and test just to be sure, because from time to time it does have a point.

Answer (score 1):

I recognize the code, that's ADO syntax.  You are battling a non-standard language extension that made COM programming easier in the previous decade.  It allowed [declaring properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yhfk0thd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on a C++ class, using the `__declspec(property)` declarator.  An example:

```
class Example {
public:
    int GetX(const char* indexer) { return 42;}
    void PutX(const char* indexer, int value) {}
    __declspec(property(get=GetX,put=PutX)) int x[];
};

int main()
{
    Example e;
    int value = e.x["foo"];   // Barf
    return 0;
}
```

The IntelliSense parser was completely overhauled in VS2010 and re-implemented by using the Edison Design Group front-end.  It just isn't compatible enough with the language extension and trips over the index operator usage.  For which they can be forgiven, I'd say.

You can complain about this at connect.microsoft.com but I wouldn't expect miracles.  The problem is still present in VS2012.  A workaround is to stop using the virtual property and use the getter function instead, `get_Item("Contact")` in your case.

Answer (score 0):

From something you said in the comments (about IntelliSense not finding a .tli file), the errors should go away once you build the solution. .tli (and .tlh) files are automatically-generated files that are created by the #import directive, but obviously you need to compile the files that have #import directives in order for those files to be generated (IntelliSense alone won't generate them).